# Wordpress: Какие варианты посоветуете по созданию динамических форм обратной связи?

Tags: wordpress

На страницу выводятся персоналии, у каждого из которых есть свой емаил. А также на каждом из них кнопка "отправить сообщение". Сообщение должно отправляться напрямую, на ящик, конкретному человеку . Как бы вы посоветовали реализовать?

Comment: Накидать формы в php, подставить туда данные персоналий, по клику через ajax отправить. Не забыть про nonce, honeypot или captcha, про очистку полей формы. Отправлять не mail(), а wp_mail()

Answer (score 1):

> Как бы вы посоветовали реализовать?

Любым плагином ОС. Тем же самым CF7. И динамика тут вообще мало играет роли. Её собсно  нет вообще.